# publish an app to cydia from appcelarator?

Tags: iphone, titanium, appcelerator, cydia

i'm trying to find a way to publish an app to cydia other than app store from titanium appcelarator so i can test the app before registration for the developer program.
are there any clear steps to build and publish the app to cydia and to the app store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go into the build/iphone folder within your project you'll find the XCode project for the app generated by Appcelerator. You can open this into XCode and build the app in the same way you would any app for distribution to cydia.

If you are just after beta testing however, check out http://www.testflightapp.com/ it allows you to distribute and manage beta testing over the air and is all legit.